# Allow a group of users to access one module in Joomla

Tags: joomla, module

I have CMS Joomla!2.5 and i want to allow for a group of users to access only one module in admin panel and nothing else. Is it possible? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can ! 
See this tutorial : https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Access_Control_List_Tutorial#ACL_Action_Permission_Examples

If you're not familiar with Joomla ACL, you should follow this tutorial from the beginning. If you are, I pointed the right place for you in the link. Simply change the article part, for your module.

Comment: I read documentation, but i need to allow access for one module (in my case CK Slideshow), not for module manager. Can i implement that?

Comment: Yes you can, go in the "Permissions" tab for that specific module and force authorize access.

Answer (score 0):

yes,it is possible,the users of your site are  in one  category:

- public
- manger
- administrator

registered

- author
- editor
- publisher
- superuser

and son on.
so for the group user you can in setting  users joomla,determine access level for users in editing your website (**according group users**).